# Check if a special row in a cell array exists in MATLAB or not

Tags: matlab, if-statement, cell-array

Please i need help but it's a little hard for me to declare it correctly in English,please be patient with me.
I've got a cell array which for example has 10 rows and 10 columns.
I fill each rows of the cell array in a loop(for) and there is this Probability that a row of it wont get any value then the result is e.g there would be rows 2 and 4 but there would n't be any third row:

```
t{2,1},...,t{2,10} exits
t{4,1},...,t{4,10} exists
but there is no t{3,1},.....,t{3,10}
```

Now i want to check if the third row exists or not?
I tried:

```
if t{3,1}
```

but it did not worked and there is not any codes like:

```
if exists(t{3,1})
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

t{3,1} does exist, it's just empty.  Therefore what you need is something along the lines of:

`if ~isempty(t{3,1})`